# Best way to start main node app from simple script

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to start an app in two different ways depending on the environment.

In package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node start.js" 
}
```

Then in the script  check the environment variable and execute the correct command:

```
// start.js
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if (env === 'development') {
    //run './node_modules/.bin/nodemon main.js' 
}

if (env === 'production') {
    //run 'node main.js'
}

//do I need to exit?
process.exit(1);
```

Is `exec`, `fork`, or `spawn` ideal here? I need no communication between start.js and the main.js, and I want the least overhead. I want it to be as close to running the environment specific command directly. My inclination is `fork` because it will start a new process and the parent will terminate.

**UPDATE**: I am not interested in alternative solutions that use multiple npm commands. I specifically want to understand the pros/cons/resource use/performance implications of starting one node script from another using the various *child_process* methods.

Comment: provided an answer, please let me know if there is anything you are unclear about - be happy to expand if needed.

Comment: Hi, please can you review my answer and let me know if you found it helpful  (upvote / mark as answer). If you require any further info, please let me know - be happy to offer further support.

Answer (score 2):

i think the approach not suitable.

in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./app"
  }
  ...
}
```

an then

`npm start`

**UPDATE 1**

If you are in windows machine just use it like this

```
set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js
```

If your machine is not a windows machine, use this

```
{
...
"scripts": {
 "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./src/server/app.js"
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: This is fine for production but it fails to start the app with nodemon in development.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do something like:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

right in the main bootstrap application file (app.js, main.js, start.js or whatever you named it) because my usual use case is development work locally. So if nothing is set, it uses development, and if I have set an environment variable explicitly it uses that (usually only set for production, but could be anything including test etc).

Then for production, you would just need to set the NODE_ENV environment variable (which cloud services like Heroku make really simple to set up when deploying to the live environment too).

Another pattern you sometimes see is:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

This is actually also updating the process.env.NODE_ENV assigned value, which means if you have other places also checking for the value of proces.env.NODE_ENV then you don't have to keep also using the "|| 'development'" check. It is not a pattern I tend to use, but you will see it in the wild.

Your **npm** scripts entry looks good, but there is nothing stopping you from defining others, calling out to shell scripts, setting env variables etc either.
If you are going to have one for production, I'd recommend making that explicit:

eg.In package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev"
    "dev": "nodemon start.js",
    "prd": "NODE_ENV=production node start.js" 
}
```

That way, there is no confusion as you have to run either:

```
npm run dev
// same as npm start
```

or

```
npm run prd
```

Above, our dev environment is executed with **nodemon**, and our production environment with **node** as requested.

**Update Based ON OP Feedback**

*which child_process method is best to start your main node app from. That was the main point of my question*

What you are asking is atypical - however, there are of course options available:

If you wanted to background the node instance, then easy to control this from the command line via bash (&) etc.

However, if you really wish to do this, then in the past I have opted to use an NPM module - [cluster](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster).

```
npm install cluster
```

This allows you to spawn child instances from a master process - in your case just set the child instance count to 1.

```
var cluster = require('cluster')
  , app = require('./main');

cluster(app)
  .set('workers', 1)
  // other configuration here
```

Finally, if you don't wish to use cluster, and really the question was more along the lines of "how to start another node.js application inside node then:

Use **child_process.fork()**. It is similar to `spawn()`, but is used to create entire new instances of V8. Therefore it is specially used for running new instances of Node.

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var child = fork('./main');
```

There are further options, please see the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) for details.

Comment: Yes, this is a good option. I could also put a bash stye if statement in `start` which uses ENV or a different variable, but this still doesn't answer my question of which **child_process** method is best to start your main node app from. That was the main point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference among `spawn()`, `exec()` and `fork()` of `child_process` as below

> `require('child_process').spawn()` starts sending back data from the child process in a stream as soon as the child process starts executing. When you run this command, it send a system command that will run on its own process rather than executing code within your node process. In this no new V8 instance will be created and only one copy of the node module will be active on the processor. It is used when you want the child process to return large amount of data to Node.
>
> `require('child_process').fork()` is a special instance of spawn thats runs a new instance of the V8 engine. Which actually means you are creating multiple workers running on the same Node code base for different task.
>
> `require('child_process').exec()` returns a buffer from the child process. The default buffer size is 200k. It is asynchronous, but it waits for the child process to end and tries to return all the buffered data at once. If your return data from the child process is greater than 200k then you will get maxBuffer exceeded.

According to the source code of [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/CLI.js#L11)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

The `child_process.exec` is used to start node.js app. PM2 also has `cluster` mode, which `culster.for()` is used here. `cluster.fork` is implemented on top of `child_process.fork`.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {  
  // Master:
  // Let's fork as many workers as you have CPU cores

  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  // Worker:
  // Let's spawn a HTTP server
  // (Workers can share any TCP connection.
  //  In this case its a HTTP server
  ...
}
```

IMO, the `PM2` is one good option to start node.js app. It also can start node.js in `development` mode with `PM2-dev`. More details could be found [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

Source:

http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/08/difference-between-fork-spawn-and-exec.html
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_fork_env

Comment: I have read the docs and the article you referenced, but was hoping for more insight into the implications of each choice. For instance, since posting the question I started an app with execFile on a 512MB server instance and it seems to be leaking memory. Perhaps because its streaming a buffer back to the parent? Further, you recommend exec because PM2 uses it, but @arcseldon recommends `fork` in his answer. I am trying to find a consensus without days of experimentation.